# How would the Stroboscopic Effect appear if the blades were reflective?

Tags: visible-light, kinematics, reflection, fan

The [Stroboscopic Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect) is an optical illusion in which rotating spokes can appear to rotate differently than the true rotation.

What will the observation be like if fan blades are coated reflective?

Comment: What illusion are you talking about?

Comment: @jameslarge - I just edited this question. But until the edits are approved, I think the OP is referring to the [Stroboscopic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect).